# Using avconv without an output file specified

Tags: shell, metadata, libav, avconv

I'm using `avconv` in the following way in order to grab ID3 data from audio files on remote servers:

`avconv -i http://myserver.com/my_music.mp3`

This command will output all the info I need, which I then parse.

The problem is, it always exits with a non-zero exit status, due to the fact that no output file is specified (since I don't want to actually download the full audio file and convert it in any way).

Is there any way I can run avconv so that it

- outputs the audio metadata of the remote file
- doesn't download the remote file in full
- returns an exit status of `0` if it was able to get this far

Answer (score 0):

How about actually downloading the file only as a temp to work on, and then automatically delete it after the work's been done?

```
avconv -i http://myserver.com/my_music.mp3 -y /temp/temp.mp3 -f ffmetadata meta.ini
# delete temp file after it's been worked on
wait
echo "Done."
rm /temp/temp.mp3
```

Keep in mind that I wrote all the above from top of my head so it may contain some errors.

In order to extract the metadata of the provided audio file, you could also use a python script.

```
>>> from pydub.utils import mediainfo
>>> mediainfo("/temp/temp.mp3")
```

and add some bash snippets inside.